# jQuery Multiple sortable save to database

Tags: database, jquery-ui-sortable

I have found a few examples of sortable and being able to save to a database, however i want to sort multiple list items and then save to the database.

I have tried to edit the code below to allow this, however i am stuck. I can move multiple items, but its only recognising the move of a single item, so presume i need to do some kind of foreach item moved but struggling.

Also, i have found a bug in the code below and cant seem to fix it. If i highlight an item(s) and drag them to the in-between the boxes, they just disappear and do not appear an either list.

Another thing i am trying to do is remove the .selected class on the selected items once the move is completed, again i am unable to do this.

```
<ul id='sortable1' class='connectedSortable'>
  <li id='item1'>Item 1</li>
  <li id='item2'>Item 2</li>
  <li id='item3'>Item 3</li>
  <li id='item4'>Item 4</li>
  <li id='item5'>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id='sortable2' class='connectedSortable'>
  <li id='item6'>Item 6</li>
  <li id='item7'>Item 7</li>
  <li id='item8'>Item 8</li>
  <li id='item9'>Item 9</li>
  <li id='item10'>Item 10</li>
</ul>

<ul id='sortable3' class='connectedSortable'>
  <li id='item11'>Item 11</li>
  <li id='item12'>Item 12</li>
  <li id='item13'>Item 13</li>
  <li id='item14'>Item 14</li>
  <li id='item15'>Item 15</li>
</ul>

$(".connectedSortable li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
$("ul.connectedSortable").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.connectedSortable",
    start: function(e, info) {
        info.item.siblings(".selected").appendTo(info.item);
    },
    stop: function(e, info) {
        info.item.after(info.item.find("li"))
    },

    update: function () {
        var order1 = $('#sortable1').sortable('toArray').toString();
        var order2 = $('#sortable2').sortable('toArray').toString();
        var order3 = $('#sortable3').sortable('toArray').toString();

        alert("Order 1:" + order1 + "\n Order 2:" + order2 + "\n Order 3:" + order3); //Just showing update
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/echo/json/",
            data: "order1=" + order1 + "&order2=" + order2 + "&order3=" + order3,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have created a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MarcellusWallis/d8exp006/1/

Comment: Can anyone help with this as really could do with a hand... Thanks